# java spingboot microservice deployment on aks throws UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes

While trying to deploy java springboot microservice on aks continuously gives me UnsupportedClassVersionError. I am using *"kubectl apply -f file.yaml"* command to apply the deployment. Even after compiling to correct compiler version now, it still complains the same. Not sure where I am missing.

**First Attempt**

 - compiled with oracle openjdk 11

 - checked compiled class version using *javap -verbose MyApplication | findstr* "major" 
  console output - major version: 55

 - Deployment to aks failed

**Second Attempt**

 - compiled with oracle jdk 1.8

 - checked compiled class version using ' *javap -verbose MyApplication | findstr* "major" ' 
  console output - major version: 52

 - Deployment to aks fails

**Common to both deployment**

 - Used command "*kubectl apply -f myapp.yaml*" to deploy on aks cluster

 - Receiving same error, which is,

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
> MyApplication has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java
> Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime
> only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
>         at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>         at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:92)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>         at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:46)
>         at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
>         at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
>         at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
```

Request kind help

Regards

Comment: hope this will help: https://www.baeldung.com/java-lang-unsupportedclassversion

Comment: what spring boot version are you using? Make sure you are using a spring boot version that supports the right jdk

Comment: While you may have compiled your code with a Java 8 compiler, it appears that the runtime classpath *still* includes classes compiled with Java 11.

Comment: Thx @Stephen, But in second attempt, I verified the compiled class major version and it shows 52 and not 55. How is this changing when I am trying in local docker, which works smooth compared to deployment on aks.

Comment: In that case, there must be another JAR or something that contains Java 11-compiled classes.  Either way, the JVM is not lying.  The error message will tell you exactly what class >>it sees<< with the wrong classfile version number.

Comment: Hi Solved this issue. The deployed pods were not pulling latest version of the image. With imagePullPolicy: Always added to yaml manifest and forcing the deployment and service to be recreated forcefully using kubectl replace --force option it deployed from the latest (fresh) image rather than using its cache. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Default pull policy is set to `IfNotPresent` which tells Kubelet to skip pulling an image if it already exists on a node where `pod` is being scheduled.
If you want to force image to always be pulled you could do following:

> - set the  `imagePullPolicy`  of the container to  `Always`.
> - omit the  `imagePullPolicy`  and use  `:latest`  as the tag for the image to use.
> - omit the  `imagePullPolicy`  and the tag for the image to use.
> - enable the  [AlwaysPullImages](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#alwayspullimages)  admission controller.
>
> Note that you should avoid using  `:latest`  tag, see  [Best Practices for Configuration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#container-images)  for more information.